# Child table doesn't get deleted

Tags: mysql

I created two tables in mysql,

1. customer
2. house table with houseID being foreign key in my customer table.

   ```
   Create customer table(
   id int not null primary key auto_increment,
   name varchar not null,
   houseId int not null,
   telephoneNo, int not null,
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (houseId) REFERENCES house(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);



   CREATE house table(id int not null primary key auto_increment,
                      houseNo int not null,
                      address varchar not null);
   ```

However, when I delete customer with a specific houseId, the row in house table doesn't get deleted though I put on delete cascade in the customer table. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key is on the wrong table. The way you got it set up is that if you delete a house, the corresponding cutomer will be cascaded.

You will want to put a customerId foreign key in the house table and have `ON DELETE CASCADE` foreign key trigger from side.

With a foreign key the ON DELETE is asking: what if the foreign key I am referencing is deleted (cascade, set null, do nothing)? **not** what to do when this row get's deleted.

Comment: Is it that I need to put customerID in house table as foreign key then?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Remember to mark questions as answered :)